# Distinct performance in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, query-optimization, aws-glue, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I am trying to populate a multiple dimension tables from single Base table.

**Sample Base Table:**

```
| id | empl_name | emp_surname | country | dept | university |
|----|-----------|-------------|---------|------|------------|
| 1  | AAA       | ZZZ         | USA     | CE   | U_01       |
| 2  | BBB       | XXX         | IND     | CE   | U_01       |
| 3  | CCC       | XXX         | CAN     | IT   | U_02       |
| 4  | CCC       | ZZZ         | USA     | MECH | U_01       |
```

**Required Dimension tables :**

1. **emp_name_dim** with values    - AAA,BBB,CCC
2. **emp_surname_dim** with values - ZZZ,XXX
3. **country_dim** with values     - USA,IND,CAN
4. **dept_dim** with values        - CE,IT,MECH
5. **university_dim** with values  - U_01,U_02

Now to populate above dimension tables from base table, I am thinking of 2 approaches

1. Get **distinct** values from base table for all above columns combination, create **single** temp table out of that and use that temp table for subsequent individual dimension table creation. Here, I will be reading data from base table only once but with more column combination.
2. Create separate temp tables for **distinct** values specific to each dimension. This way we need to read base table for **multiple** times, but created temp table will be smaller(i.e. less number of rows and only single column's distinct values).

Which approach is better if we consider for performance?

**Note :**

1. Base table is huge containing millions of rows.
2. Above columns are just for sample. In actual table there are around 50 columns for
   which I need to consider for distinct combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scanning the large table only once is the way to go.

Also there is another way to get the distinct values which in some cases will be faster than distinct.  As an alternative approach perform a "group by" on all the columns.  Run this as a bake-off to see which is faster.  In general if there will be a small number (fits in memory) number of resulting rows from distinct, then distinct will be faster.  However, if the result will be large then group by will be faster.  There are a lot of corner-cases and factors (distribution style) that can impact this rule-of-thumb so testing both for speed will give you which is faster in your case.

Given that you have 50 columns and you want all the unique combination I'd guess that the output set will be large and that group by will wind but this is just a guess.